# How to return an existing view from a new action in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Noob needs help!) How can I return an existing view from a new action within the same controller?
For example I have a following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View(); //returns Index.cshtml
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string id, string condition)
{
     SomeModel.ID = id;
     SomeModel.Condition = condition;
     return View(SomeModel); //returns Index.cshtml delegating the model
}

public ActionResult someAction()
{
     return View(); //How to make this action return Index.cshtml??
}
```

Comment: `return View("Index");`

Comment: I tried to do this way, but I face an error

Comment: @user3493623 What kind of error?

Comment: Potentialy dangerous Request.Path value has been received from a client (translated from russian)

Comment: @user3493623 I'm afraid your problem is something else, then. There is probably more code you're not showing us and it's related to the error.

Comment: Nothing more. '<span><a href="@Html.ActionLink("Bla", "Bla", "Home")">General@example.com</a></span>' - that's how I use it as a link. "Bla" is a link text and an action name

Comment: And how does link look like? I think the error is here.
It should be: "sitename/controllerName/someAction"

Comment: [Great question, amazing answers...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling another different view from the controller using mvc 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910530/calling-another-different-view-from-the-controller-using-mvc-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the view name to return:

```
public ActionResult someAction()
{
     return View("Index"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult someAction()
{
     return View("Index"); //How to make this action return Index.cshtml??
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add

return View("YourView");

If you want send a model to it you can do this

var model = new YourViewModel
{

}

return View("YourView", model);