# How to have a drop-down list lead you to logging into different pages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

(EDITED)
I want to mimic the functionality of "user roles".

When logging in, the user will enter their username and password, then , using a drop down list on the same page, will select an item (role), click the "login" button, and if successful, be directed to a specific page.

So if user selects item "Admin" in drop down, he should be redirected to "_AdminLanding"
.. and 
if item "Student", redirected to "_StudentLanding".. And if  item "Tutor", redirected to "_TutorLanding"

My code is as follows:

MODEL:

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Tutors.Models
{
public class UserAccount
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="First name required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required")]

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Username required")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password",ErrorMessage="Password required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

LOGIN SECTION -- CONTROLLER

```
    public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
    {
        using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
        {


            var usr = db.UserAccounts.Single(u => u.UserName == user.UserName
                && u.Password == user.Password);

            if (usr != null)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = usr.UserName.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is incorrect");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

---

The user roles i want to have are namely; Tutor,Admin,Student.
The pages i would like each user to be redirected to are namely; "_TutorLanding","_AdminLanding","_StudentLanding". For the moment, it redirected to the page "LoggedIn" as i did not want to change it just yet

Comment: Can you explain which part you are having difficulty with?  eg where to begin? Adding the property to model? Rendering the dropdown? Getting the property back to the action?  Processing the property into the redirect action name?

Comment: @freedomn-m . I am unsure where to begin. I basically need the property to get back to the action , and then through the action, the property selected from the list needs to redirect me to either "_AdminLanding","_StudentLanding" or "_TutorLanding"

Comment: You have different problems to be addressed, please ask a specific question so we can help

Comment: Add a string property to your class for `public string UserRole { get;set; }`.  Add `@Html.DropDownFor(model=>model.UserRole...`  (I'll leave you to find how to add select items...) for the `select`.  In your login action, `return RedirectToAction("_" + usr.UserRole + "_Landing");`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, here's what you'd like to happen:

1. On button click (login), validate username and password.
2. If validation fails, go back to 1. Else, check the current item selected on your drop down list.
3. If drop down list is equal to x, and user is under role x then redirect user to form x. Else if drop down list is equal to y, and user is under role y, redirect user to form y. etc.

Hopefully you'd get to understand the flow of the solution this way.

Also, I suggest that you should instead have a "role" column or entity to identify the role of the user logging in, without the prompt of a drop down list. Since base on what you have described, any registered user is capable of accessing any specific roles, as long as the user has valid credentials entered on your app.

Comment: yes! thats basically what i need. However, i  am new to mvc and dont particularly know how to code this. By far, ive just followed a tutorial that assisted me on obtaining this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is choosing which view to load after authentication. Can you clarify your intended result when "redirecting"?

[Calling another different view from the controller using ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910530/calling-another-different-view-from-the-controller-using-asp-net-mvc-4)

The accepted answer is to return a new View or PartialView object.

```
return View("NameOfView", Model);
```

SO after you do your authorizing. Switch on the drop-down value, returning a view as needed.

```
switch(dropdownList1.SelectedValue)
{ 
     case "Tutor": return new View("_TutorLanding",Model);
     case "Admin": return new View("_AdminLanding",Model); 
     default:break;
}
```

or short-hand the code.

```
return new View($"_{dropdownList1.SelectedValue}Landing", Model);
```