# How to return to same url after submit button clicked from different ActionResult method in same controller using MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I want **url** to be remain same what it was before after submit is clicked, I don't want to display `ActionResult` method name

> Before executing below code, my url was `http://localhost/ProjectName/`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ControllerSignIn(Models.SignIn signin)
{
    ViewBag.name = "John";
    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
}
```

> After executing the above code, my URL become `http://localhost/ProjectName/ControllerSignIn/`

**I tried below code also**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ControllerSignIn(Models.SignIn signin,string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.name = "John";
    return View(returnUrl);
}
```

**my partial view code**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerSignIn", "Home"))
{
    //.... some text box
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-rounded" value="Login" id="btnLoginSubmit" />
}
```

**Note**

> My point is, wherever user logged in, after they logged in, it has to visit the same url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling another different view from the controller using ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910530/calling-another-different-view-from-the-controller-using-asp-net-mvc-4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that URL determines which controller and action should be executed. What you pass to a View() is not a URL, but a path. This path determines which view should be displayed...

```
// no matter what you put in "SomePath", your URL will remain the same.
return View("SomePath");
```

---

If you want to change the URL to http://localhost/ProjectName/ you need to redirect to that Controller's action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ControllerSignIn(Models.SignIn signin)
{
    ViewBag.name = "John";
    /* return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"); <-- this has no effect on URL */
    return RedirectToAction("MyController", "MyAction"); // this would take you to a different URL
}
```

If you want to redirect to: http://localhost/ProjectName/ (I assume ProjectName is your Controller and you want to redirect to the default action)... you need to return:

```
return RedirectToAction("ProjectName"); // redirect to default action of ProjectName controller
```