# Can you have a one to many relationship using Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

With Razor pages is it possible to create many web pages from a single Razor page?

For example instead of using query strings like:

```
example.com/Movies?ID=1
example.com/Movies?ID=2
...
example.com/Movies?ID=999
```

Create all these from a single Razor page (a single physical razor page on your dev machine):

```
example.com/Movies/1
example.com/Movies/2
...
example.com/Movies/999
```

I know the opposite is true via changes in routing having many URL's relate to a single Razor page.

Comment: yes you can.. it is bit old fashioned but you can create HTML in c# and pass to ViewBag.

Comment: So you want the latter URL format instead of the first one? Routing does the job

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling another different view from the controller using ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910530/calling-another-different-view-from-the-controller-using-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: I am not sure if that answers my question. I know Razor pages are built on top of MVC but at the same time the asp.net core team has suggested that Razor pages is the recommended path to build a website. Not sure if Razor pages are intended to generate webpages in the manner I asked or if it is something you need/should use regular MVC for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using .Net Core 3.1 and Razor Pages:

[image]

In Movies.cshtml you add on line 1 `@page "{ID:int?}"`

[image]

In Movies.cshtml.cs you check the value of ID and do something useful with it.

[image]

In the browser it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is the key piece of information I was missing. Kept reading how @page was a necessary directive for declaring a Razor page and thought that was all it was good for. Didn't realize you could do custom routing like this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try routing in RouteConfig.cs OR You can redirect in controller.

In 2.Option you can create a table like this

ID | URL 
1  | link1 
2  | link2

And in controller you can get link from table and redirect to URL.