# ASP.Net 5.0 Call Controller Function on Button/Link Click in View

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm just learning ASP.NET Core 5.0 and Entity Framework Core. I have a simple function in one of my controllers to add the number 1 to a database upon click.

When I click the link, the value is added to the database correctly, but the View crashes. If I call the function on initial page load it works fine, but calling it from a button click is just not working for me. Either nothing happens at all, or the function is called but I get a null reference exception, depending which of my attempts it was.

**MyAppController.cs**

```
public IActionResult InsertNewActionNumber()
{            
    _context.RGWActions.Add(new RGWAction { ReduceMeat = 1 });
    _context.SaveChanges();
    Debug.WriteLine("*******************TEST2********************TEST2*********************");
    return View();
}
```

Link in `MyApp.cshtml`:

```
<td class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-table-cell d-xl-table-cell" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
    <a href="@Url.Action("InsertNewActionNumber", "MyApp")">
        <img src="@Model.MouseClickIconThumbnailUrl" id="MouseClickIconRow1" width="20" height="35" alt="Mouse Click Here Image">
    </a>
</td>
```

When I click the link, the value is added to the database correctly, but I hit a null reference exception on the `return View();` for the first line in the View itself  `ViewData["Title"] = _loc[Model.PageTabTitle];`

```
@model MyAppViewModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using MyApp.Data
@using System.Globalization
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = _loc[Model.PageTabTitle];
}
```

I have also tried:

1. On-click as per [this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1939073.aspx?Invoke+a+controller+action+by+a+button+click). But the function is not called at all.
2. `@Using` as per [this link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/how+to+call+controller+function+on+button+click+mvc+net+core). Also no joy.
3. Razor Syntax `<a href="" asp-action="InsertNewActionNumber" asp-controller="ReduceGlobalWarming"></a>` but I get an *InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'href' attribute for*   error.
4. Variations of the first 10 or 15 results from google and stack overflow.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated?

Comment: So, your view expects a model and you aren't returning a model to your view from the controller.   This appears, to me, to be a good case for an AJAX call instead of using a button to post to the controller.  I say that because it doesn't appear that your controller method is operating on the model as a whole, but just incrementing a property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a model to you view. This is way it crashes:

```
public IActionResult InsertNewActionNumber()
{            
    _context.RGWActions.Add(new RGWAction { ReduceMeat = 1 });
    _context.SaveChanges();
    
 var model= ....your code

    return View(model);
}
```

or instead of creating model again you have to  call your get insert form action

```
public IActionResult InsertNewActionNumber()
{ 
_context.RGWActions.Add(new RGWAction { ReduceMeat = 1 });
    _context.SaveChanges();
 
    return GetActionNumber(); // <= replace with your get action name
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped but I am now getting a different error "System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'InsertNewActionNumber' was not found. The following locations were searched:" I don't know why its looking for a view with that name, that's the name of my function as specified in the <a> element.

Comment: By convention/default, asp.net MVC controller uses the method name for the view (i.e insertnewactionnumber.cshtml).  You need to have this view `views/MyApp/insertnewactionnumber.cshtml`.

Comment: Will that just be an empty view - An empty .cshtml file? Obviously my function name does not have to match the name of the View where the button is, or I could only have one function? Likewise, I cannot need a  fully populated view for every function, or my app will be bloated with copies of every page?

Comment: Just tested, the view loads and is empty. The error is gone. So I need a fully populated view for every single function? How do I prevent my app getting bloated with copies of every page? Is there no way to simply call a function from a button like I do in Android? Thanks again for all your advice, and patience.

Comment: @DMur Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910530/calling-another-different-view-from-the-controller-using-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: I don't understand where my "get action name" can be found? But the link above from @sanmcp has solved it. Thanks to you all for your help.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to advise you the same. I usually use the save view for add new and  update or edit action.  In the end of addnew action I usually call edit action with returns the same view with new data.